# Disable local delivery ONLY for authenticated users in Qmail

Tags: smtp, email, mx-record

We are moving some mailboxes and servers.
I'm looking for a way to use remote delivery (with normal MX lookup) instead of local delivery ONLY for authenticated users, in Qmail.

- connection to port 25 without auth => allow delivery to local Maildir
  for mydomain.com
- connection to port 25 with auth => use remote
  delivery for all messages

I tried to play with smtproutes conf file, but this file is ignored by Qmail, when the domain is known as local because it exists in virtualdomains ...

Thanks for any idea !
Olivier